# Error while buying apps in Google Play store in Android Jelly Bean

Tags: google-play-store

Anyone on the Android Jelly Bean OS and not able to buy Apps/Books through wallet? I have just bought the Samsung GalaxyNote 800 and am facing this issue.

The error is (RPC:S-7:AEC-0).

What is the solution?