# Error retrieving information from server

Tags: applications, google-play-store, system-info

Whenever I try to download an app from Google Play Store, it allows me to accept the App Conditions but I don't see it downloading. A sign that shows there's an error pops up, 'Error retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-0 ZVSF-VF44-KHLR]'.

What should I do? Please help. I need to download an app.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please, 1) see our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) for explanations to error messages, 2) see [questions on the same error](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=RPC%3AS-7%3AAEC-0) on our site, 3) good luck! Oh: 4) [Error while buying apps in Google Play store in Android Jelly Bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44873/16575) deals with exactly the same error code.

Comment: This answer was applicable in my case: [Google play fails to install application with RPC:S-5:AEC-0](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34466)

Answer (score 0):

> Goto Settings > Apps > All > Clear Cache and Data for these apps >
>   Play store, Download manager and Google Services framework.

Remove you google account from your `Account > Google` section under your phone `Settings`.

Reboot your device and add your google account back and then try to download/update the apps from the Playstore.

Comment: Might or might not solve it. According to [Error while buying apps in Google Play store in Android Jelly Bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44873/16575) (raising the very same error code) it could also be the attached credit card has expired ;) But yes: that's the "generic fall-back" to most errors with GPlay ;)

Comment: Yes i agree but the OP hasn't mentioned he is buying/downloading a  paid app. So I just posted a generic first aid solution which solved the problem for many. Other reasons also include corrupted sdcard, credit card expiry. etc. :)

Comment: Agreed, Lucky. I just found that relation by using our search on the error code. And mentioned it just in case – it might "ring a bell" with the OP (or other readers), saving them from "unnecessary work" :)