# Tried various solutions but still receiving the error code [RPC:S-7:AEC-0 XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX]

Tags: google-play-store, system-error

Once I was able to download apps from Google Play. But later, I disabled Download Manager for two days, then re-enabled it and opened Google Play to download apps but it started showing the following message whenever I tapped download.

> Error while retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-0 XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX]

And XXXX marked letters change every time whenever I tap download.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

- I cleared data and cache of Google Play, Google Play Services and Google Services Framework
- I removed the account and re-added it

But none of them worked.

- I uninstalled Google Play updates, Google Play Services and reinstalled them --  didn't work as well.
- I flashed my phone. So I got back my phone as new one -- it didn't work either.

I am just fed up now. I did everything as suggested. But none of them works. Please someone make solution to this problem.

Comment: Even after a factory reset, is there something in your Android that could be blocking some services of Google Play Services or Google Services Framework? [I once had this problem](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/google-play-fails-to-install-application-with-rpcs-5aec-0#comment151574_34466).

Comment: Please take a look at our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) – where you will find the corresponding information (for many playstore issues). In your case: [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44873/16575) (linked from there) deals with the "RPC:S-7:AEC-0" error – and you've almost described the solution from there: you might just have missed a reboot between removal and addition of your account. BTW: "RPC:AEC:0 error is known as CPU/RAM/Device/Identity failure." So your device brand and model might be relevant.